# How to add action on the title of Google Maps maker in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to add action to the title of Google Maps

I am using code like this

```
for (int i=0; i<NameHSArray.count; i++) {
    double LatitudeDouble = [LatitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
    double LongitudeDouble = [LongitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatitudeDouble, LongitudeDouble);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.title = NameHSArray[i];

    if([TypeHSArray[i] isEqualToString:@"ESIC"])
    {
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon2.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon1.png"];
    }

    GMSCameraUpdate *zoomCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate zoomIn];
    [mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:zoomCamera];

    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

As in the Image

[image]

How to add the action when I click on Nobel Hospital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `GMSMapViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    // your click action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**OBJECTIVE C**

> set delegate

```
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

> method

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker)marker 
{
NSLog(@"yes"); // do something
}
```

**SWIFT**

```
mapView_.delegate = self
```

> METHOD

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
print("yes")
// do something
}
```